# For which $a$ the solution is defined on the interval

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> For which $a$ the solution of $$\begin{cases} \frac{z'}{z^2}= e^{-x^2} \\ z(0)=a \end{cases}$$ is defined on the interval $[0,\infty)$

**My try:**
$$\frac{z'}{z^2}= e^{-x^2}$$ $$\int \frac{z'}{z^2} \,dx=\int e^{-x^2}\,dx$$ $$-\frac{1}{z(x)}+C=\int e^{-x^2}\,dx$$ $$z(x)=\frac{1}{\frac 1a -\int e^{-x^2}\,dx}$$ I think that this equation has the solution when exist $z'$.

$z'(x)=\frac{e^{-x^2}}{(\frac 1a - \int e^{-x^2}\,dx)^2}$ so exist when $(\frac 1a - \int e^{-x^2}\,dx)$ doesn't converge  to $0$

However, I do not know how it matters for the range given in the task. Can you help me finish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $\int e^{-x^2}dx=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}erf(x)+\text{constant}$ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function) and thus we can write $z(x)=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{a}-\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}erf(x)}$=$-\frac{2a}{a\sqrt{\pi}erf(x)-2}$. This is defined when $a\sqrt{\pi}erf(x)-2\neq0$, and is equal to zero when $a=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}erf(x)}$, in fact it is defined on the interval $(-\infty,\infty)$ for $-\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}
<a < \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} $ (play around with values of a on here https://www.desmos.com/calculator/wkqyixrgxc). Then using the fact that $erf(0)=0$ and $erf(\infty)=1$ we have that on the interval $[0,\infty)$ :

- $a\leq z(x) <-\frac{2a}{-2+a\sqrt{pi}}$ for $a<\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}
  $

Comment: For $x\in [0,+\infty)$ we have $\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi} \erf{(x)}}\in [\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2},+\infty)$ so is the answer should not be $z(x) <-\frac{2a}{-2+a\sqrt{pi}}
$ for $0<a<\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\ , -\infty<a<0$? In your answer is only $-\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}<a$ not $-\infty<a$

Comment: Ok, I know that $a$ not be bigger than $\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$ but I didn't ask about it. I asked about second interval - why you have  $-\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}<a<0$? I think your answer is good but when $x\in (-\infty, +\infty)$ and in $x\in [0,+\infty)$ should be $-\infty<a<0
$

Comment: Yes for $∈(−∞,+∞)$ we have $−∞<<0$ but we are looking at the interval $∈[0,+∞)$ and for $a<0$ we have $z(0)=a<z(\infty)=-\frac{2a}{-2+a\sqrt{\pi}}$.

Comment: Maybe I do not understand something, but if so explain it to me because I think I found more errors in your solution. In first comment you write that $\text{erf}(0)=1$, but it is not truth - $\text{erf}(0)=0$. This is chart of $\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi} \text{erf}(x)}$ in $x\in [0,+\infty)$: https://imgur.com/a/4huklLZ . This function takes values $[\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}, +\infty)$. In my task we want to $a \neq$ this function . So we want to discard the blue area and leave it green, because there our function is not specified. So for $x\in [0,+\infty)$ we have $a\in (-\infty, \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}})$

Comment: Sorry for the typo in my comment, I've written it correctly in the answer above. Yes the function$\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}erf(x)}$ is defined for $x>0$ and $x<0$ and we are only interested in $x>0$. Next we look at $z(x)$ which is defined on the interval $∈[0,+∞)$ for $a<\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}$.

Comment: Ok, so the last question - now you agree with me that if we were considering $x\in (-\infty,+\infty)$ then $a \in (-\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}, \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}})$?

Comment: Yes because $erf(-\infty)=-1$ so that $z(-\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}})$ is not defined, but we are considering the interval $∈[0,+∞)$.

Comment: Ok, I'm glad everything is finally cleared up! Thank you very much for help